# Blender mesh having random holes and bulges at specific areas

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, edges

I've been trying to make a Gameboy Model for a while now but I've been having some problem at certain areas of the mesh. In the image, I cant seem to get rid of the bulging area of the mesh and make it completely flat and seamless. How do I fix this? There are also various random holes in mesh with no edges nearby so I dont really know how to fix them.[image][image]

Comment: please provide your blend file. it looks like a loop-cut

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-0mPWTYmQc1 heres a link to the .blend file

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to the subdivision modifier you're using. Subdiv modifiers don't handle complex corner geometries too well, such as this one.[image: vert with lots of edges connected]

If you can manage to distribute this more evenly, with fewer edges connected that one vertex it should work.

On top of this, you might want to think of remodelling the topology across that front area to some degree, subdiv modifiers give weird outputs when there are varying levels of detail (i.e. big faces in some places, and lots of tiny ones in others).